# Editing GVFS mounted files using Emacs

Tags: linux, emacs, ssh, sftp

When I'm working with remote files (over SSH/SFTP), Emacs always saves the files with permission `700`, but any other editor (e.g. GEdit) maintains the previous permission of `770`.

Is there any way to configure Emacs such that it does not change the file permissions?

Comment: mh I don't know. I open files via GNOME... I'm newbie with emacs, however this is the message after saving:
"Wrote /home/federico/.gvfs/SFTP for federico on 10.10.1.10/var/www/test.php"

Gedit and other editor haven't this problem...

Comment: Ok I'm not in Tramp mode. I open files via Gnome, and Gnome mount remote dir with GVFS. It is mounted in "/home/user/.gvfs/SFTP for user on 10.10.1.10/" . But I've got this problem only with emacs and only with remote files...

Comment: I've deleted my previous comments so as to reduce noise. Can you have a read through what I posted and let me know.

Comment: I have the same problem with gvfs and GVim

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So [here's](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/227808) something that may help. The bug I linked to describes your situation almost to a tee (substituting vim for emacs). Someone there posted a workaround you could try:

> ...after installing sshfs (fuse was already installed), then mounting
>   the remote server by creating /mnt/servername, and using `sshfs
>   user@servername:/path/ /mnt/servername/ -p port`, I was able to use
>   gvfs to navigate to /mnt/servername and open, edit and save the file
>   using GVim without problems. This is both a workaround, and perhaps
>   useful in narrowing down the problem.

Of course, the easiest (and quickest) solution will be to use [Tramp Mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TrampMode):

```
C-x C-f /user@10.10.1.10:/var/www/test.php
```

Comment: That bug is opened from 2008! :( Where are gvfs developers? :D So, 
Tramp mode is a perfect and simple solution. Thanks :)